# Variations in this prepositional phrase

Tags: grammar

May I ask if there is any difference in the meaning of the below two example prepositional phrases? Are they both grammatical? Thanks!

This apartment has drawn far more purchase orders, **with its price lowered**.
This apartment has drawn far more purchase orders, **with its price being lowered**.

Answer (score 2):

You'd say "with its price lowered," but you wouldn't need a comma before "with." Also, I'm questioning your use of the word "apartment," like maybe you mean "department"?  I don't know.  An "apartment" is real estate.  You can't have a "purchase order" for real estate.  In real estate, the term is "purchase agreement" because purchasing real estate can't simply be ordered by the purchaser as it requires a signed agreement by both parties, meaning the seller must voluntarily sign an agreement to sell.

Comment: Thanks @Billy! But how about "with its price being lowered." Is this also grammatical and is there any difference between the connotations of the versions with and without "being"? Thank you!